# Google Firebase declaring data types

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to save my object in firebase database in order to retrieve it later again.

```
{title: "Zombie", start: Tue Jan 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), end: Tue Feb 06 2018 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (CET), color: {primary: "#696969", secondary: "#D1E8FF"}, priority: "Low", …}
```

However, whenever I save the data to the firebase database, it stores everything as a string. Since, the start and end attributes are date objects, and to be able to store them in a calendar, they need to remain objects. When firebase saves the whole object, it converts everything to a string including the start and end attributes. Is there a way to store the object into firebase as it is shown above? Or like in Angular through an "any" data type?

Edit:

What firebase returns (everything was converted to a string):

```
{color: {primary: "#696969", secondary: "#D1E8FF"}, end: "2018-02-06T22:59:59.999Z", priority: (and so forth).......}
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, you can convert a string date to an actual date using:

```
const start = new Date(item.start);
```

Or if it's bound in a template, you can just use the date pipe:

```
   {{ item.start | date }}
```

Comment: I have been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours...Thank you so much!!! It worked!